# How To run TypeScript in Eclipse?

Tags: angular

I am a newbee to Angular 2.0 and I am stuck with transpiling Typescript as I am a java guy. Can anyone help me on how to transpile TypeScript code in Eclipse?

Comment: Why not use vscode, it's lightweight and powerfull

Comment: Tried VSCODE, but facing the issues of npm. So trying other solution.

Comment: What issues are you facing there? Also did you already try [TypEcs](http://typecsdev.com/)?

Comment: I am getting npm cli issue and aslo npm is not able to recognise npm-debug.log even though it is present. i simple had the code from: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted

Comment: thanks for TypEcs. I ll Try it.

Comment: Even i have uninstalled node js and installed it again. i have set the path in environmental variable and again installed the npm. but still getting the same issue, it cannot locate npm-debug.log and npm-cli. the same installation i did in my friends laptop its working fine there. can any one help??

Comment: Rephrased the question for readability.

Comment: Please try https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started